# Breaking news in the top of the form

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a form which in the top of it i put a label.
In this label, whenever user open the program, this label will connect to the PasteBin Site. ( a site which you can paste or type whatever you want and at the end you can create a link about whatever you typed.)
Now i could create a breaking news in the top of the form and it works great.
But this will happen only once. let me put my code here first :

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebRequest.Create("http://pastebin.com/raw/vkABdKag");
    lblNews2.Text = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://pastebin.com/raw/vkABdKag");
    lblNews2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
}
```

But this will happen only once.
I mean even i change the text in this URL, again last text will be show.
It seems that the program download the text only once and it will show it at the top of the form.
Now this is my question.
How can i put this code or what code should i add to this code, that whenever user open the program, first program check this link for if the text in this URL has been changed or not.
Is it any code like : refresh or reload or ... for this function ?
Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Doesn't pastebin create a new url for each edit?

Comment: No i don't think so. If you edit your text in text bin i don't think Create a new url.

Comment: From what I see, is not your label that "whenever user open the program, this label will connect to the PasteBin Site" is your form., When you opening that form,  the form is making the request. if you want to make the request when the user input modify the text from label, you have to attach to Changed label event and post your code from your load method.

Comment: Well, pastebin is not going to tell you when the bin changed.  So you'll have to poll, use a Timer.

Comment: @HansPassant Would you please tell me how can i do this ?
i donnow how i do this.

Comment: Add a `Timer`to your form, set its `Interval`, code its `Tick` event and `Start` it.

Comment: @TaW I did whatever you said but nothing happened. at the first of the form (when form is loading) nothing happened. Even when i code : timer2.Start();

Comment: @TaW unfotunately not...
Would you please put codes witch you mean in the answers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First put the download code into a separate function, so you can call it as needed:

```
string getNewsFrom(string url)
{
    string content = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);
    return content;
}
```

Next pull a `Timer` component from the Toolbox onto the `Form`. Call it `newsTimer`. Set its `Interval` to a time you like.

```
newsTimer.Interval = 5 * 60 * 1000;   // set the timer to tick every 5 minutes
```

Doubleclick the `Timer` component and code the resulting `Tick` event:

```
private void newsTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblNews2.Text = getNewsFrom(yourUrl);
}
```

This assumes you have a class level variable `yourUrl` that holds the url you want to use.

If you want to, add a `CheckBox` to your Form and name it `newsListening`. Doubleclick it to create the `CheckedChanged` event and code it like this:

```
private void newsListening_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newsTimer.Enabled = newsListening.Checked;
    if (newsTimer.Enabled) newsTimer_Tick(null, null); do one download immediately!
}
```

If you want the timer to run all the time you can `Start()` it in the `form_Load`; if you want to use the `CheckBox` and start with the `Timer` running, trigger the `CheckedChanged` event by putting a  `newsListening_Checked = true;` in the load event!

Now you will get the current content updated every five minutes and can start and stop the timer.

Note that you don't need a `WebRequest` when you use a `WebClient`.